# Swift Error IBOutlet with xib file

Tags: ios, xib

In my project, I want to display a popup and the view of this popup is defined in a `.xib` file.
To do that I use this line of code :

```
 myPopupView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NibView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

Until then, it works. But the problem is when I try to add an `IBOutlet`. My Xib file is connected to a uiviewcollection, and I manage to create an `IBOutlet` on the `Textfield` I have in the xib file. But when now I run again my app, I have this famous message :
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key...

So if I look on Internet, everybody says to delete the `IBOutlet` by clicking on the cross button in Inspector, BUT I don't want to delete it because I need this `IBOutlet`. So isn't it possible to have IBOutlet in a xib file ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very common error which means the `IBOutlet` you have taken in .xib is not connected to the relevant class. This kind of error I experience when i have taken a outlet and given some name like `lblUserName` but later i renamed that to lblFriendName, then the label in xib is still connected to lblUserName as well as lblFriendName, so at the time of compilation the xib did not find the connection for lblUserName and throws error.

**So go to your xib, right click on the outlet in the xib, then you will see the cross button to disconnect. So disconnect it and connect it again.**

During that also you can see the connection name, it must be wrong name or there would be two connection foe the same label in which one would be correct and another must be wrong (This case when you rename a connection as i explained)

Hope you understand, and it helps...

Happy coding ...

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, but unfortunately it still doesn't work, even if I have tried a lot of time to disconnect the outlet and connect a new one. But I have maybe seen the issue. Actually the complete error message is : [<MyApp.ProjectsController 0x7b9808e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnCreate    ...   But the name of the Controller for this XIB file is not ProjectsController   but  NewProject .... Is it possible that the xib file is connected to the wrong controller ? But in Inspector I have defined the good one

Comment: If you can describe the connection and show some pictorial view of connection then it might help me to find the issue quickly..

Comment: If you have copied the xib from some other project then that xib would be pointing to the wrong connection as it is not there. As per your described comment, btnCreate's connection has problem.

Comment: So actually I have created a new xib file by clicking on "New file.../CocoaTouchClass/" then I have selected "subclass of UIViewController" and I have checked "Also create XIB file.  I have named them "NewProject".  Then I have another UIViewController named ProjectsController, and in this one I execute the code :   var viewCreateProject = UIView()

        viewCreateProject = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NewProject", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView)!

Comment: And after that, I display the UIView "viewCreateProject" thanks to a cocoaPods lib, with this line of code : "presentPopupView(viewCreateProject)"

Comment: And that's all... The problem is that, even if in my NewProject Xib file I have well selected in the Inspector "NewProject" as class,   it thinks that the viewcontroller is not NewProject but  ProjectsController

Comment: And indeed, if I add the Outlet in ProjectsController it works fine, but if I add the outlet in NewProject, I have the error message, because it can't find it

Comment: Yes you might have selected wrong VC. Check that too. Any way i hope you got your answer, correct

Comment: Ok, so if I well understand, it is not possible to load a Xib file connected to a controller, if this Xib file is run in another controller...  I don't know if I'm clear, as it is not really clear for me :), but I know now why it doesn't work so it's good ! Thanks for your help !! :)